# dc.js - data labels for bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have this below code for the bar chart using the `dc.js`.

```
barChart = dc.barChart('.bar-chart-container')

barDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return d.bar; })
barGroup = barDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return d.count; });


barChart
.margins({ top: 10, left: 50, right: 10, bottom: 150 })  
.width(1200)
.height(500)
.dimension(barDimension)
.group(barGroup)
.x(d3.scale.ordinal())
.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
.gap(5)
.elasticY(true)
.renderlet(function (chart) {chart.selectAll("g.x text").attr('dx', '-35').attr(
        'dy', '15').attr('transform', "rotate(-45)").attr("text-anchor", "end");})
.renderlet(function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll("rect")
    .append("text")
    .attr("text", function(d) { return d.value })
})
```

I wanted to add the data labels to the bars.

But unfortunately that is not avaiable in the dc.js.

I tired adding new element using the `.renderLet` and I was successful in it.

But I don't have any idea how to put the exact number on the selection.

Whereas the for `rowChart` and `pieChart` we can use the label function to add the data labels using `d.value` which is not available for the bar chart.

Is there any way we can add the data labels on top of all the bars in `dc.js`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show values on top of bars in a barChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026010/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-a-barchart)