# Smaller values not being shown in dc.js bar chart

Tags: dc.js

I have 5 bar charts(in a composite chart) plotted using dc.js. I have noticed that in few bar charts, for a few dimensions where the values become very small compared to others (**please note that these are non-zero values**), still they drop down to the X-axis as if their values are zero. Even the tool-tip for these bars don't show up so that the user may figure out that these values exist and are not actually equal to zero as it looks. How do I fix this issue??Is there a way I can show these bars, however small they be!This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This problem with all forms of visualization, not just dc.js. The generally accepted solution (as recommended by Bill Cleveland, among others) is to use a log scale, e.g. specify `.y(d3.scale.log())`:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#log

However, this is often not used because people are not always comfortable with log scales, especially those with less math skills. Also, since log 0 = **∞** and dc.js hasn't been completely debugged for log scales, [you may need to apply some workarounds](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/477#issuecomment-490295301).

Another suggestion in this particular case is to add a label for the value, as shown here:

[Show values on top of bars in a barChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026010/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-a-barchart)

and then make clicking the label work the same as clicking the bar. (I have not checked if this solution does that; if it does not, please comment there. The author, @dimirc, has offered to do a PR.)

Comment: I am getting `Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "Infinity".`

Comment: @Pygirl, I think the workaround linked above should fix that error for bar and line charts, if not please comment on that GitHub issue. Thanks!