# dc.js: Adding Totals to Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart in dc.js with the totals label at the end of the charts. Right now, I can't find any documentation on parameters or functions to pass through that'll allow it to happen.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have some source that you can put up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show values on top of bars in a barChart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026010/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-a-barchart)

Comment: it's not directly supported, but the linked question and answer show how to add it post-hoc. please comment there if you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon, you are correct that this is a duplicate of a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026010/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-a-barchart) that you mentioned in a comment!

However, I found the answer didn't work because `.renderlet` chaining was removed. Here's a reworked version of it that worked for me (kinda, there is still issue of it's not showing up if the bars are too small).

Thanks for everything!

```
  testChart
  .width(400)
  .height(200)
  .dimension(testDim)
  .group(testGroup)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)

  testChart.on('renderlet', function (chart) {

    var barsData = [];
    var bars = chart.selectAll('.bar').each(function (d) {
      barsData.push(d);
    });

    //Remove old values (if found)
    d3.select(bars[0][0].parentNode).select('#inline-labels').remove();
    //Create group for labels
    var gLabels = d3.select(bars[0][0].parentNode).append('g').attr('id', 'inline-labels');

    for (var i = bars[0].length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

      var b = bars[0][i];
      //Only create label if bar height is tall enough
       if (+b.getAttribute('height') < 10) continue;

      gLabels.append("text")
          .text(barsData[i].data.value)
          .attr('x', +b.getAttribute('x') + (b.getAttribute('width') / 2))
          .attr('y', +b.getAttribute('y') + 25)
          .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
          .attr('fill', 'black');
    }
  });
```