# dc.js: Bar Totals with ElasticY

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I'm trying to implement bar totals at with bar charts in a very similar manner as you would with row charts. For row charts, the code would be

```
    Chart
      .width(500)
      .height(500)
      .dimension(chartDim)
      .group(chartGroup)
      .title(function(d) {
        return d3.format(",f")(d.value); // or your custom value accessor
      })
      .renderTitleLabel(true)
      .titleLabelOffsetX(50)
      .xAxis().tickFormat(function(v) {
        return "";
      });
```

This will return a chart with the values of it at the end of the row charts with the `elasticX` functionality. However, when it comes to bar chart, you would have to implement a `renderlet` solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008191/dc-js-adding-totals-to-bar-chart) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026010/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-a-barchart) where you have to manually draw the bar totals.

The issue I have with this approach is that 1) the y domain isn't elastic, so if there are wide variations in your selections, the bar totals may not show, and 2) you have to manually determine the range for the y axis.

Is there a more elegant way to create bar totals in a more elegant way without relying on the `renderlet` solution, something preferably similar to the row chart solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no more elegant way, until this feature makes it into dc.js proper.

However, there is a solution to the problem you're describing: the coordinate grid mixin does support internal padding, `yAxisPadding`, to reserve extra space when `elasticY` is enabled.

This should keep the labels inside the bounds.

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#yaxispaddingpadding

Answer (score 0):

`yAxisPadding` works, but you'll end up with padding both above and below the bars, which is rarely what you want.

If you overwrite the `yAxisMin` function with something that always returns `0` you should be set, however, e.g.:

```
timeChart
  .height(200)
  .brushOn(false)
  .elasticY(true)
  .x(d3.scaleBand())
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
  .yAxisLabel('Entries')
  .yAxisPadding('10%')
  .renderLabel(true)
  .dimension(timeDimension);

timeChart.yAxisMin = () => 0;
```