# Text labels on crossfilter bars do not appear

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to append value labels to the bars of a Crossfilter frequency bar chart in line with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468049/1156245), but can't get it to work.  The data seems to be being passed through correctly; it does appear in the DOM, but is not visible.  Grateful for any tips.

Here's [my working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geotheory/ue7d5qwf/).

[image]
HTML

```
<span>
  <div id="petchart"></div>
</span>
```

JS

```
j = [{'pet': 'Felis catus'}, {'pet': 'Canis lupus familiaris'}, {'pet': 'none'}, 
        {'pet': 'Felis catus'}, {'pet': 'Melopsittacus undulatus'}, 
    {'pet': 'Canis lupus familiaris'}, {'pet': 'Canis lupus familiaris'}];

cf = crossfilter(j);
pets_chart = dc.barChart("#petchart");
petDimension = cf.dimension(function(d) {return d.pet;});
petCountGroup = petDimension.group();

pets_chart
  .dimension(petDimension)
  .group(petCountGroup)
  .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["Felis catus","Canis lupus familiaris","Melopsittacus undulatus","none"])) 
  .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)

  pets_chart.on("renderlet", function(d){
    pets_chart.selectAll("rect")
        //.selectAll("text").remove()
        .append("g").attr('class', 'selection_total')
        .append("text")
        .data(petCountGroup.all())
        .attr("text", function(d) { console.log(d); return d.value; })
  })

    .width(300).height(250)
  .colors(['#1f77b4']).colorAccessor(function(d, i){ return i; })
  .xAxis().ticks(2);

dc.renderAll();
```

CSS

```
g.selection_total text{
  font-size: 1em;
  fill: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/p1j10mgx/7/

The main problem with your former code is that it was putting `<text>`objects within `<rect>`s, which is not feasible.
Instead, you need to add them under an higher `g` block, say `".chart-body"`. Then the main trick is to get the coordinates right.

For the coordinates I used the solution you mentioned ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25468049/1156245)) and gave the set of `<rect>` objects as `data` to the labels. Then you get the coordinates directly from the `<rect>` object itself, and all additional information you might need is within the object's own `.data()` field.