# How to show values stacked bar chart utilizing dc.js and d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, dc.js, crossfilter

[Based on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026010/show-values-on-top-of-bars-in-a-barchart), I was able to create a bar chart using dc.js and d3.js with labels. However, I turned the bar chart into a stacked bar chart (based on [this documentation](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html)), and I'm having difficulty showing the labels for each of the stacks.

For example each stack in the below chart should show the number, but it's showing [object Object]

[image]

See below for code and here for [codepen](http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/vXyggP?editors=1010)

Javascript

```
var data = [{Category: "A", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "A", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "A", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "A", ID: "2B"}, {Category: "A", ID: "2B"}, {Category: "B", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "B", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "B", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "B", ID: "2B"}, {Category: "B", ID: "3C"}, {Category: "B", ID: "3C"}, {Category: "B", ID: "3C"}, {Category: "B", ID: "4D"}, {Category: "C", ID: "1A"}, {Category: "C", ID: "2B"}, {Category: "C", ID: "3C"}, {Category: "C", ID: "4D"}, {Category: "C", ID: "4D"}, {Category: "C", ID: "5E"}];

var ndx = crossfilter(data);

var XDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.Category;});



var YDimension = XDimension.group().reduce(
    function reduceAdd(p, d) {
      p[d.ID] = (p[d.ID]|| 0) + 1;
      return p;
    },
    function reduceRemove(p, d) {
      p[d.ID] = (p[d.ID]|| 0) -1;
      return p;
    },
    function reduceInitial() {
      return {};})


dc.barChart("#Chart")
    .width(480).height(300)
    .dimension(XDimension)
    .group(YDimension,"1A",function(d) {return d.value["1A"];})
    .stack(YDimension,"2B",function(d) {return d.value["2B"];})
    .stack(YDimension,"3C",function(d) {return d.value["3C"];})
    .stack(YDimension,"4D",function(d) {return d.value["4D"];})
    .stack(YDimension,"5E",function(d) {return d.value["5E"];})
    .transitionDuration(500)
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(XDimension))
    .renderlet(function (chart) {

    //Check if labels exist
    var gLabels = chart.select(".labels");
    if (gLabels.empty()){
        gLabels = chart.select(".chart-body").append('g').classed('labels', true);
    }

    var gLabelsData = gLabels.selectAll("text").data(chart.selectAll(".bar")[0]);

    gLabelsData.exit().remove(); //Remove unused elements

    gLabelsData.enter().append("text") //Add new elements

    gLabelsData
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .text(function(d){
        text_object =  d3.select(d).data()[0].data.value
        return text_object
    })
    .attr('x', function(d){ 
        return +d.getAttribute('x') + (d.getAttribute('width')/2); 
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){ return +d.getAttribute('y') + 15; })
    .attr('style', function(d){
        if (+d.getAttribute('height') < 18) return "display:none";
    });

})


dc.renderAll();
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dc/1.7.0/dc.css" media="screen">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.site44.com/dc3.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/NickQiZhu/dc.js/master/web/js/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id='Chart'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't get what the difference is between this question and the other one - please close one or the other. http://stackoverflow.com/q/39580578/676195

Comment: I don't recommend using the code from the first part of the answer to the question you've linked - it's not idiomatic d3 code and it's hard to troubleshoot. If you instead you use the second code provided by @dimirc, it shows labels for all the stacks. Incidentally, [`renderLabel`](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#dc.baseMixin+renderLabel) is now implemented for bar charts - but it only draws a label for the top bar. If you care to contribute to dc.js, you could add an option to draw labels for all bars.

Comment: Fork of your codepen using the other code, showing labels for all stacks: http://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/xERGVE?editors=1010

Comment: @gordon - Thanks for your feedback. The two questions were similar, so I merged the two questions here, deleted the other one, and made an update based on your codepen here. However, the values are still not showing in my stacked bar chart: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/vXyggP?editors=0010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically what I do in these situations is put a breakpoint on the line in question and poke around and see if the object contains the data that I want somewhere else.

It looks like you can use `.datum().y` here:

```
    text_object =  d3.select(d).datum().y
```

http://codepen.io/gordonwoodhull/pen/EgNvNr?editors=1010

[image]

This is still kind of weird code (using DOM elements as data for a data join for some other elements is pretty hacky) but hopefully this will get you moving.

Comment: Thanks so much, as I spent hours trying to figure this out! This definitely got me moving! Thanks again.

Comment: Can you tell what's syntax for showing value text on dc js line plot? https://jsfiddle.net/elangobharathi/Lqbcye5u/5/ <-- this is in d3.js .

Comment: Hi @Pygirl, I am confused because the [renderLabel](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/BaseMixin.html#renderLabel__anchor) feature has existed for both line and bar charts for a long, long time. So I'm not clear why there was a question about it in 2016. Here's a [dc@4.0.3 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/fd04wnbk/4/) and here is a [dc@3.2.1 fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/d7squLzh/3/) demonstrating the feature for line charts.

Comment: But I don't know why I aint getting the label when I even use renderLabel. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60924803/unable-to-show-the-line-in-decreasing-way-in-dc-js I applied it on it but still the same.

Comment: I tried all the solution but it didn't work but when put the code with some minor modication on jsfiddle it's seems to work. But not working in my laptop.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhc68emf/ <-------- Working here but not in my laptop :/ even it's showing me downward line

Comment: Yes, I saw your other question and hope to take a look today. I don't understand why labels would work on one machine but not another, sorry. SVG is usually pretty stable if you are using a current browser.

Comment: Is it because of crossfilters, dc, d3 js files I copied the code and put it inside a file then called it via script. because giving the link it was giving me error (loading file failed).

Comment: I thought you meant that the fiddle worked in one place but not another, which I have seen only rarely. If you're copying files and setting up different configurations, then, well, probably *something* changed. :) Not sure how I can help with that.

Comment: I made it to work by copying all the required file from jfiddle to my desktop and run it the same piece of code it's working but now the issue is I ain't to load my csv file. d3.csv(.............. is not working for me now.

Comment: @Pygirl, it looks like some of your code is d3@3 and some is d3@5. This could explain `d3.csv` not working, since [the function has moved to a Promise-based API](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50).

Comment: Thanks for that made it to work. Can you tell me how can I change the xaxis of this graph since I am having crossfilters when I select on some other chart this chart should be rendered decreasing way xaxis labels should also change.  I am looking for a function for that.

Comment: I think this is the question you have already asked and linked above.